# Sharepoint 2013 to crawl sharepoint 2007 site

Tags: access-denied, crawl

I have a SharePoint 2013 (named SP2013) and I would like to use it to crawl another SharePoint 2007 site (named SP2007) on the same LAN. Account for search service is the administrator of SharePoint site and two sites use the same id/pass. Whatever I tried there is an error always as shown

[image]

1. I checked the access account. It's the site administrator of SP2007.  Therefore permission shouldn't be an issue.
2. Modify "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa" was not worked
3. Here is the setting in sp2007 ( which will be crawled ), the search account is the same on both sp2013 and sp2007.

[image]

Is there anyone knows how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the crawl-account (Default Content Access account) of your SharePoint 2013 to your 2007 *Policy for Web application* in Application Management in Central Administration. Give the account full read permission.

http://SP2007CentralAdminURL/_admin/policy.aspx

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply.  Yes I did that before.  The search account for sp2013 and sp2007 is the same domain account and it's the administrator of both sharepoint sites.  Thus I think the permission should be enough for search account.

Comment: @ScottieLin If this answer solved your question, please mark this answer as the accepted one and it may be useful for future visitors. Thank You! :)